# Print all elements of an hex array in one line

Tags: c, arrays, hex

I have an array in C `char arr[100]`, each element of which may contain an arbitrary hex value (even 0). I want to somehow be able to print this array in one line, for example:

```
arr[0] = 0x11
arr[1] = 0x00
...
arr[99] = 0x22
```

The output should be:

```
0x11 0x00 ..... 0x22
```

If I use a `printf()` with `%s`, it will stop at 0. I don't want to use a `for` loop to print each character one by one using `%x`. I have constraint of which API I can use because of the system I am working on. It does not allow `printf()`. It has a function `print()` which adds a new line after every print, but accepts format strings like `%x, %s, %d` etc. like `printf()`.

How can the requirement be achieved ?

Comment: Provide the body of the *`print()`* function in that case...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sprintf` to copy in to a buffer, then print the buffer

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char arr[] = { 0x11, 0x00, 0x22, 0xFF };

    int count = sizeof(arr);

    //each element needs 5 bytes
    char *buf = malloc(5 * count + 1);

    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        sprintf(buf + i * 5, "0x%02X ", arr[i] & 0xFF);

    //optional: remove the last blank space
    buf[5 * count - 1] = 0;

    printf("[%s]\n", buf);//or whichever print function available

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can devise your own function to construct a string first and then print it at once. You can do it as:

```
void print_array(char arr[], int len) {
    if(len <= 0){
        print("");
        return;
    }
    char output[len*5];
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<len;i++) {
        output[i*5]='0';
        output[i*5+1]='x';
        int upper = (unsigned char)arr[i] / 16;
        int lower = (unsigned char)arr[i] % 16;
        output[i*5+2] = upper < 10?(upper + '0'):(upper-10+'a');
        output[i*5+3] = lower < 10?(lower + '0'):(lower-10+'a');
        output[i*5+4] = ' ';
    }
    output[i*5-1]=0;
    print("%s", output);
}
```

This obviously makes some assumption about char width and encodings. But you can adjust according to your target.

Here is a working [Demo](https://ideone.com/teWslx).

Comment: You include a trailing blank that could/should be avoided, and reduce the allocation needed for `output` by 1: `char output[len*5];` and `output[i*5-1] = '\0';`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler that is assuming `len > 0`. I will just add a print at the beginning incase len is 0 and adjust the rest like you suggested.

Comment: Yes; printing empty arrays isn't exciting and can be dealt with (`assert(len > 0);` for example, or `assert(len > 0); if (len == 0) return;` if you're worried about debug vs production).

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way by far is just using recursion. In fact the program below can be further compacted by using only the main function, and declaring the index as a global variable.

```
#include <stidio.h>
//declare your array and its size as a global varaible
int arrSize = 5;
unsigned char arr[5] = {0x00, 0x11, 0x1F, 0x33, 0x34};

void recursion(int i) {
    if(i == 0){
        printf("0x%x0 ", arr[i]);
   }else{
       printf("0x%x ", arr[i]);
   }

   if(i < arrSize -1){ //at index i, if i is less than the length of your array
       i += 1;
       recursion(i); //then recurse to the next index
  }else{
       printf("\n");
  }
}

int main() {
    recursion(0); //call your recursive function in main()
}
```